# Does it make sense to say “We came to code”

Tags: writing-style

My mother language is German and I am working as IT professional.

I am about to write a small manifesto on some professional values for a group of people. Since writing source code is more or less the main activity of a programmer does it make sense to use  “We came to code –  and to build something valuable” as the title of the manifesto?

Comment: I see no problem with "We Came to Code" – so long as you don't mind evoking an image of grim-faced, talented, purpose-driven programmers (pocket protectors not included).

Comment: `me.takeOffence(true); me.slap(jr);`

Comment: ... unless you *are* writing a Ladungsverzeichnis eines Schiffes, of course.

Comment: Since _come_ isn't transitive, it can't take an object infinitive, so any infinitive following _come_ is likely to be a **Purpose** infinitive. Test: substitute _for the purpose of `V`-ing_ instead of _to `V`_. Does it mean the same thing? If so, it's a purpose infinitive. Same reason why _stop smoking_ and _stop to smoke_ don't mean the same thing; _stop_ also can't take an object infinitive, so it hasta be a purpose infinitive.

Answer (score 5):

The phrase "we came to code" is perfectly acceptable as a title. There are other examples of this scattered throughout literature and you can use virtually any variant:

- We came to rock
- We came to rule
- We came to eat cake